# Do you need a Sphero to use the Sphero SDK?

Tags: sphero-api

So I finally found a programmer to program my ["Orb Warriors"](http://forum.gosphero.com/archive/index.php/t-815.html) game idea I had posted on the original Sphero Dev forums a while back.

Since I know very little about programming, and will be doing the graphics part of the game,  I was wondering will he actually need a Sphero to set up and use the SDK?  Or will he be able to program and then send me test builds of the APK to test it with my Sphero?  He does not have a Sphero yet, but hopes to get one soon.
He lives like 1200 miles away from me, so I guess if he needs it for programming I can mail him my Sphero for the time being, but I was trying to avoid that as I still use my Sphero.  :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, he will need a Sphero to use the SDK.

Comment: OK thanks for the reply Ross, we will try to work something out. :)